# android: how can get full path of a file stored in a folder in sdcard?

Tags: android, sd-card, android-sdcard

I am working in android. i want to get the full path of a file selected  by user. my files
are stored in sdcard. but may be in a folder in sd card.

I have some folders in my sdcard. I want to get the full path of a file on which i click.

Suppose I have an image `peacock.png` in folder image/birds.

So the path is `mnt/sdcard/image/birds/peacock.png`

Please suggest me how can i get the full path of a file.

If you need my code which i am using for help then tell me i will send it here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you know what files to show the user if you don't already know the path?

Comment: sir i have a file chooser program, i which all file and folder are displayed then user can easily select a file to which he want to select. should i send my file for this functionality ?

Comment: please see my file for file chooser, so you can easily suggest me that what should i do to get full path selected by user. please see this file  http://www.mediafire.com/?c2860mcfb3vf9bf

Comment: I added an answer below after checking your file.  Does that help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a code snippet from [this](http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_pick_a_file_with_an_Intent.rhtml) tutorial, that shows the pick file Intent implementation:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
{
   if (requestCode == PICK_REQUEST_CODE)
   {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
   {
      Uri uri = intent.getData();
      String type = intent.getType();
      LogHelper.i(TAG,"Pick completed: "+ uri + " "+type);
      if (uri != null)
      {
         String path = uri.toString();
         if (path.toLowerCase().startsWith("file://"))
         {
            // Selected file/directory path is below
            path = (new File(URI.create(path))).getAbsolutePath();
         }

      }
   }
   else LogHelper.i(TAG,"Back from pick with cancel status");
   }
}
```

As you can see, your `onActivityResult()` method returns you the `Intent`, which contains the file path, that can be extracted using `intent.getData()` method. Then you just create a File object using this path, and get the absolute path of it using `file.getAbsolutePath()` method. Hope this helps.

Comment: firstly the tutorial you have given is not valid url. and the code you have written is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean in the onFileClick, it is passed an Option. Your Option class seems to contain the full path, as it is passed into the constructor, for example:

```
new Option(ff.getName(),"Folder",ff.getAbsolutePath())
```

Can't you get at that property somehow?