# Get absolute path of Android file

Tags: android, file, android-intent

I have the below code which lets the user select a pdf file from there device, however currently it seems the passed URI path is no absolute.

```
public void openPDF(int type){

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select PDF "), type);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (requestCode == SELECT_PDF_CV)
            {
                System.out.println("SELECT_PDF");
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                cvselectedPath = selectedImageUri.getPath();
                System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO Path : " + cvselectedPath);
            }

        }
    }
```

as an example when I select a file from the downloads manager in the emulator `cvselectedPath == /document/3`

When the file selected is actually /sdcard/downloads/sample.pdf

How do I get the actual absolute path to the file so I can then create a `File` object ready for processing.

Code given in the comment does not work as I am getting a content: uri with it so

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
                String type = data.getType();
                Log.i(TAG,"Pick completed: "+ uri + " "+type);
                if (uri != null)
                {
                    String path = uri.toString();
                    if (path.toLowerCase().startsWith("file://"))
                    {
                        // Selected file/directory path is below
                        path = (new File(URI.create(path))).getAbsolutePath();
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG,"path completed: " + path);

                }
```

gives

Pick completed: content://media/external/file/2007 application/pdf
path completed: content://media/external/file/2007

Comment: Look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726119/android-how-can-get-full-path-of-a-file-stored-in-a-folder-in-sdcard

Comment: Tired that code however `Log.i(TAG,"Pick completed: "+ uri + " "+type);` gives me "Pick completed: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3 null"

Comment: You are going **wrong** way. There's may be no real file (or nothing you'd be able to access directly). So fix your app to properly deal with content provider provided content.

Comment: 'File object ready for processing.'. What are you going to do to process the file? Open a (File)InputStream? Then you don't need a File object or filesystem path.