# Android reading data from xlsx

Tags: java, android, file, path, xlsx

I'm trying to read data from an xlsx, in Android. I have this code, to choose a file, and the read function to get some data from the chosen xlsx.
I get a path of the xlsy like this:

> content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/root_files/storage/1EF>7-0EF8/Documents/export.xlsx

But the read function gives me a filenotfound exception.
So my question is, how should I get the proper path of the file?

```
public void onBrowse() {
        Intent chooseFile;
        Intent intent;
        chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        chooseFile.setType( "*/*");
        intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) return;
        if(requestCode == ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE)
        {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            Log.d(TAG, "uri path: "+uri.getPath());
            read(uri.getPath());
        }
    }

private void read(String path) {
        try {
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(path));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "read: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " sheets");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have this extra space on this line `chooseFile.setType( "*/ *");`

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS deleted the extra space, but I still get the same filenotfound exception

Comment: What's this class `WorkbookFactory.create(new File(path));` doing?

Comment: i'm following this guide: https://www.callicoder.com/java-read-excel-file-apache-poi/  .  "Creating a Workbook from an Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)"

Comment: What is `uri.getPath()` returning?

Comment: The part in the blockquote. "content://com.mi.android.globalFileexplorer.myprovider/root_files/storage/1EF>7-0EF8/Documents/export.xlsx"

Comment: Can you try getRelativePath or getAbsolutePath instead please?

Comment: I can't call them to a Uri, tried to create a File from it (path = (new File(URI.create(path))).getAbsolutePath();) but the app dies here

Comment: I tried it like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726119/android-how-can-get-full-path-of-a-file-stored-in-a-folder-in-sdcard  
But my path starts with content:// not file://

Comment: @MátéAntal Which library you are using for reading xlsx?

Answer (score 2):

Must cast content uri to file path

```
public class FileUtil {
     public static String getFileAbsolutePath(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (context == null || uri == null)
            return null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                String[] split = docId.split(":");
                String type = split[0];
                if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
                }
            } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
            } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                String[] split = docId.split(":");
                String type = split[0];
                Uri contentUri = null;
                if ("image".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                    contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                }
                String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";
                String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
                return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
            }
        } else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            // MediaStore (and general)
            // Return the remote address
            if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                return uri.getLastPathSegment();
            return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
        } else if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE.equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
            // File
            return uri.getPath();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        String column = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA;
        String[] projection = {column};
        try {
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                return cursor.getString(index);
            }
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is ExternalStorageProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
     */
    public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
        return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }

    /**
     * @param uri The Uri to check.
     * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
     */
    public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
        return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
    }
}
```

use

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
Log.d(TAG, "uri path: "+uri.getPath());
String path = FileUtil.getFileAbsolutePath(this, uri);
Log.d(TAG, "file path: "+path);
read(path);
```

Comment: Tried it with your code. Got this:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/1EF7-0EF8/Documents/export.xlsx: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Answer (score 0):

To read xlsx file

Add following dependencies, in build gradle

```
implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.0'

implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.0'
```

use following code

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook

// change this if not using file from resources directory
val file= this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("data.xlsx")

val pkg: OPCPackage = OPCPackage.open(file)
val wb = XSSFWorkbook(pkg)

val rowNumber = 0

val columnNumber = 1
val sheet0 = wb.getSheetAt(0)
println(sheet0.getRow(rowNumber).getCell(columnNumber))
```